# SSIS Incremental Load-15 mins

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, oledb, lookup

I have 2 tables.  The source table being from a linked server and destination table being from the other server.
I want my  data load to happen in the following manner:

1. Everyday at night I have scheduled a job to do a full  dump i.e. truncate the table and load all the data from the source to the destination.
2. Every 15 minutes to do incremental load as data gets ingested into the source on second basis. I need to replicate the same on the destination too.

For incremental load as of now I have created scripts which are stored in a stored procedure but for future purposes we would like to implement SSIS for this case.

The scripts run in the below manner:
I have an **Inserted_Date** column, on the basis of this column I take the max of that column and delete all the rows that are greater than or equal to the **Max(Inserted_Date)** and insert all the similar values from the source to the destination. This job runs evert 15 minutes.

How to implement similar scenario in SSIS?

I have worked on SSIS using the lookup and conditional split using ID columns, but these tables I am working with have a lot of rows so lookup takes up a lot of the time and this is not the right solution to be implemented for my scenario.

Is there any way I can get **Max(Inserted_Date)** logic into SSIS solution too. My end goal is to remove the approach using scripts and replicate the same approach using SSIS.

Comment: What is your question here? You don't ask anything (there's not a single "?" in your "question").

Comment: You would do it exactly the same way your stored procedure does it. Just with different ways to set and apply variables.

Comment: @Larnu Is there any way I can implement SSIS Incremental Load using max date functionality.

Comment: @KeithL Could you please guide some steps to configure the same?

Comment: @VidyaNambiar Larnu would simply answer "yes" to that question. We expect a level of effort by posting what you have tried and help make recommendations on how to better implement what you have tried. This kind of request really asks us to do all the effort.

Comment: @KeithL Thanks the below solution worked, I used a variable and used that in a Execute SQL and Data flow task and got the desired flow I was looking for. Script task component I did not explore as I am not familiar with C# scripting

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general Control Flow:

[image]

There's plenty to go on here, but you may need to learn how to set variables from an Execute SQL and so on.